# pandas division on groupby keeping remainder

Tags: python, pandas, division

I'd like to perform division on column with 2 digit precision, but I need to make sure it sum up to desired number (200) on groupby level.

I'm not sure what's the best way to approach this.

Example:

```
vehicle   |  count  |  result   |  calculation

ford      |    2    |   100     |  round(200/count, 2) = 100
ford      |    2    |   100     |  200 - 100 = 100
chevrolet |    3    |   66.67   |  round(200/count, 2) = 66.67
chevrolet |    3    |   66.67   |  round(200/count, 2) = 66.67
chevrolet |    3    |   66.66   |  200 - 66.67 - 66.67 = 66.66
```

Comment: I dont get it. Can you explain how you get calculate the result column?

Comment: Please, elaborate on what exactly you want to divide, and what result you expect.

Comment: Please do not post images when you could post text. We cannot copy from an image!

Comment: Guys, I've updated my question. Hope it's clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the residual to the last element of the group, i.e.

```
df['result'] = df.groupby('vehicle', as_index=False).transform(lambda gr: round(200/len(gr), 2))
def add_resid(gr: pd.DataFrame):
    gr['result'].iloc[-1] += 200 - gr['result'].sum()
    return gr

df['result'] = df.groupby('vehicle', as_index=False).apply(add_resid)
```

Still apparently if you have a big group, this will accumulate error. Another way to do this is to assign the residual in a "rolling" way.